# Android Studio package names

Tags: android, android-studio

What are the package names like "com.example.etc." in Android Studio representing? Does it actually have any association with the domain and website? Many tutorials I have read state to use a domain name you own. Why is this?

Comment: To ensure uniqueness. No two apps on play store have the same package name. Domain name is usually a good choice. Using/having a domain name isn't a requirement though.

Comment: @Vikram See response to FR073N below. Thanks.

Comment: No. If you _do_ have a domain name, its preferable to use it for two reasons: 1. Its unique by design(domain names are unique). 2. It provides useful information to users. They might try to check if you have a website for the app.

Answer (score 1):

When releasing your application on the market, your application needs an unique package name. This will correspond to the ID on the market.

So choose a package name like your own domain, or your name... in order to have something unique.

Comment: So it has nothing to do with the internet and actual domains?

Answer (score -1):

Your package is is your `Id` when U upload in play store , It will recognize only by `Id` which is package name ,
Please give as `com.companyname.appname`.